# Is it safe to use Flash Login system?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm currently developing a Flash based game and I'm wondering if it is safe to use a flash Based Login system. If not, why?

How can someone "hack" on the login form? Is there something available for flash like Fireforce which is a Firefox extension to bruteforce passwords. I would like to know what kind of threats out there before I build a login system.

I have used google but didn't found any useful information.

Comment: The login system belongs **on the server**. The login client is not important, because this is not the resource being protected. If anything of value coexists in the login client, you've probably gone wrong.

Comment: The above is the correct answer.